# Mesh-сеть на Rust

Tags: сеть, wifi, rust

Интересует вопрос переведение вайфая в ad-hock и организации простейшей mesh-сети. Какие есть решения для языка Rust, что б было кроссплатформенно, эффективно и без решений типа netsukuku, hiperboria, cjdns. Надо передавать мелкие даные.

Comment: Немного непонятен вопрос. Rust — низкоуровневый язык, mesh-сети — высокоуровневая абстракция. Я так понимаю вопрос в том, как управлять wi-fi карточкой из раста (в частности переводить её в ad-hoc режим)? Если вопрос в этом, то точно так же, как и с помощью Си: импортировать системные функции с помощью `extern "C" {...}` и обернуть их в безопасную абстракцию, а для кросс-платформенности использовать условную компиляцию с помощью атрибутов `#[cfg(target_os = "windows/linux/whatever")]`.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что этот вопрос слабо относится к раст как таковому, он больше про системное API.

Answer (score 2):

Немного подумал и решил всё же ответить. Готового решения, увы, нет. Но поскольку, судя по всему, имеется в виду использование wireless API, то нужно просто импортировать нужные функции из системных библиотек с помощью [FFI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) (например [cм. этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102186/wireless-api-for-linux-in-c-or-java)).

Если не хочется заморачиваться с FFI, то можно просто вызывать нужные команды (вроде "iwconfig" для линукса) через [Command](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html).